# Responsive Sidebar does not work properly in the smartphone version

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a problem with sidebar of this page. I can not make it go under in the responsive version, especially in the smartphone version. Sidebar remains attached to the contents of the left but does not wrap

[This](http://codepen.io/creasso/pen/rrpPgW) is the link for the codepen
If codepen does not work, this is the [link](http://www.alchimieadv.biz/ricette/) for the website.

```
archive-posts-w.with-sidebar .archive-sidebar {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative;
    top: inherit;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
    bottom: inherit;
    right: inherit;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
```

`Html` there will certainly be errors because it is a copy of a source of a website wordpress.

Comment: problem in codepen?

Comment: do not load or does not work the link?

Comment: the result is blank. Now worked

Comment: so now what you want to do can u please more explain?

Comment: in short, the right sidebar of the homepage in the responsive version for smartphone fits like I would not, that does not wrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

Your container `.archive-posts-w.with-sidebar` has `display: table;`. Change that to `display: block` for smaller screens (i.e. in your media query)

The CSS for the part above your sidebar should be like this (for smaller screens):

```
.archive-posts-w.with-sidebar .archive-posts {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And for `.archive-posts-w.with-sidebar .archive-sidebar` you have a `max-width` setting of 350px, also inherited from everal other rules, so change this rule  (for smaller screens) to

```
.archive-posts-w.with-sidebar .archive-sidebar {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative;
    top: inherit;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;/* <-- this one is changed */
    bottom: inherit;
    right: inherit;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First add class table td in that td class="test"

```
td.test
{
 display:block
}

#sb_instagram .sbi_header_text .sbi_bio, #sb_instagram .sbi_header_text h3
{
      margin:0px!important;
}
```

#sb_instagram .sbi_header_text .sbi_bio, #sb_instagram .sbi_header_text h3
In that class you have     'margin: 0 0 0 60px!important;' you change that 0px
abd check the devices 
http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http://www.alchimieadv.biz/ricette/&device=ipad&orientation=portrait